# update toolbar making trouble switch cards sencha

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch

I have cards in my web app that each one of them has a top toolbar.
After I update one of them, I have a problem to switch cards (it's stuck).

I gave each toolbar an id and I'm Updating by using the following code:

```
Ext.getCmp('cashiertoolbar').update("<div><img style=\"margin-top:5px;\"  
src=\"images/lottoLogo@2x.png\"  width=106px height=33px/> &nbsp <img style=\"margin-top:0px;   
margin-left:-15px;\" src=\"images/nav_line.png\"/></div><div style=\"display:run-in;margin- 
top:-48px;margin-left:100px;color:#516691;font-weight:bold;\">&nbsp Hi"+ " "+ firstname + " " + 
lastName+ "." +"</div><div style=\"margin-top:-5px;margin-left:110px;display:run-in;color:#FFF;
\">Balance</div><div style=\"display:run-in;\"></div><div style=\"display:run-in;margin-top:-22px;
margin-left:173px;\"><img src=\"images/nav_cashier@2x.png\" width=143 height=22\"/></div><div 
style=\"display:run-in;font-size:12px;margin-top:-24px;margin-left:185px;
\">"+CurrencySymbol+balance+"</div>");
```

When I switch cards couple of times it's worked out.
Thanks for any help,

Comment: I think you are putting a very nasty html in the toolbar. Make it a simple html with simple styles. Then test it and then modify the html.

Comment: I don't thing that's the reason although I'll try it.

Comment: As I thought, This is not the problem.
Does anyone know how to figure it out?

Comment: Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: By the way, any kind of update causes a problem. Even a simple one. And do componentlayout doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
Just change the getCmp to get...
Good luck!